# Updating entities with OneToMany mappings: Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, hashset, hashcode

I have a requirement where I need to update the entities on either side of a ManyToMany mapping.
I have a **InsurancePolicy** entity-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "insurance_policy")
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class InsurancePolicy {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="policy_id")
    private long policyId;

    @Column(name="policy_name",nullable = false,unique = true)
    private String policyName;

    //Short description
    @Column(name="policy_description",nullable = false)
    private String policyDescription;

    //Long description
    @Column(name="choose_description",nullable = false)
    private String chooseDescription;


    //many policies can belong to one category
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
    private Company company;

    //many policies can belong to one category
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id",nullable=false)
    private Category category;



    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "policy", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE},fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<PolicyCounty> policyCounties = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and **PolicyCounty** entity-

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="policy_county")
public class PolicyCounty {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="policy_county_id")
    private long policyCountyId;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="policy_id")
    private InsurancePolicy policy;



    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "county_id")
    private County county;

    @Column(name="cost",nullable = false)
    private double cost;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="policyCounties",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<UserPolicyQuery> userPolicyQueries=new HashSet<>();

    @PreRemove
    public void preRemove(){
        //remove the relationship with policyQueries
        for(UserPolicyQuery userPolicyQuery: this.userPolicyQueries){
            userPolicyQuery.getPolicyCounties().remove(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to write a method to update the **InsurancePolicyEntity** such that the attributes in the **InsurancePolicy** table are updated. For **PolicyCounty** mappings, some **PolicyCounty** entities might have their **cost** attribute updated and it is also possible that **new PolicyCounty entities need to be created at the same time**.
**Problem-**
Since I am using **Set**, I am not sure whether something like this would yield correct results-

```
 @Transactional
    @Override
    public InsurancePolicyResponseDto updateInsurancePolicy(InsurancePolicyCreateDto insurancePolicyDto) {
        long id= insurancePolicyDto.getPolicyId();
        InsurancePolicy insurancePolicy=this.insurancePolicyRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Policy with id "+id+" not found"));
        insurancePolicy.setPolicyName(insurancePolicyDto.getPolicyName()); //update name
        insurancePolicy.setPolicyDescription(insurancePolicyDto.getPolicyDescription()); //update description
        insurancePolicy.setChooseDescription(insurancePolicyDto.getChooseDescription()); //update choose description
        Set<PolicyCounty> policyCounties=insurancePolicy.getPolicyCounties(); //get the policy counties
        for(Map.Entry<String,Double> countyPricePair: insurancePolicyDto.getCountyCosts().entrySet()) {
            PolicyCounty policyCounty=this.policyCountyRepository.findByPolicyIdAndCountyId(id,Long.parseLong(countyPricePair.getKey()));
            //if there is some new mapping
            if(policyCounty==null){
                policyCounty=new PolicyCounty();
                policyCounty.setPolicy(insurancePolicy);
                County county=this.countyRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(countyPricePair.getKey())).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("County with id "+countyPricePair.getKey()+" not found"));
                policyCounty.setCounty(county);
                policyCounty.setCost(countyPricePair.getValue());
                this.policyCountyRepository.save(policyCounty);
            }
            else{

                policyCounty.setCost(countyPricePair.getValue());
                this.policyCountyRepository.save(policyCounty);
            }
            policyCounties.add(policyCounty);
        }
        InsurancePolicy savedPolicy=this.insurancePolicyRepository.save(insurancePolicy);
        return this.policyToResponseDto(savedPolicy);
    }
```

I am asking this question because the **hashcode** method for the **PolicyCounty** entity will be changing, so will it reflect for the OneToMany relationship? For new **PolicyCounty** needs to be created and mapped with **InsurancePolicy**, will it occur correctly? Please help me understand how **hashcode** and **equals** are working in such mappings?

Comment: Sets are fine as long as you don't have different instances of your entities - JPA maintains entity identity for you, so if you read PolicyCounty1 and UserPolicyQuery1 through the same context, you'll see that PolicyCounty1 will reference the same UserPolicyQuery1 instance in its set - so the java default hashcode and equals will work (for standard settings). Your code is fine if it is within the same transaction: It is only when you get to copies read in diff contexts things fall apart, as separate instances for the same data will have different hashcodes.

Comment: I am performing all these steps within a single transaction. If anything fails, everything will be rolled back. I tested the API and its working, but I don't know if anything can go wrong with this approach.

Comment: If you are looking for pain points - I think you know them, and I don't use sets since lists work just fine for the most part. But the issue still exists regardless; if you have two java instances for the same row data, you need to find your own ways to determine that they really are the same. JPA does that automatically with the entity ID values, and this code is doing something similar by pulling the IDs out and using JPA to find 'the' entity in the current context for that data - it is the right approach.